Set Up Two-Factor Authentication on a Linux Desktop
Google Authenticator  can be set as two-factor authentication  on a linux desktop,is there other two-factor authentication application  ,instead of Google Authenticator, that can work on linux desktop?

This question is similar to: TOTP authenticator. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
